# How to use querySelectorAll based on length of the value

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, selectors-api

This is a rather specific question but I am trying to use querySelectorAll for all 'a' tags that have a 'href' value that is a specific length AND does not contain 'html' at the end of that value.

I understand the basics of querySelectorAll but not how to accomplish something like this...

Thank you for any help offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it's not possible to impose any sort of length restriction on attribute values using selectors.

The closest you can get is this, without the length restriction:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href]:not([href$="html"])');
```

Comment: @Soryn: Sure, simply chain multiple `:not()` selectors after one another.

Comment: actually this brings me to a new question... can I use :not like that for things anywhere in the value?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm guessing you can just replace `$=` with `*=` and it'll work...

Comment: guess that's as close as I'm going to get.... going to make for one long statement but i'll make it work.